# What typically gets sent to the ISS?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, astronauts, mission-design, life-support

I'm working on a project that aims to understand what is needed to live in space. I understand the basic concepts and vital items needed, but I'd love to see a direct example of what is already being done.

Considering we already have to think about this every time we send a resupply cargo spacecraft to the ISS, I figured there might be a list somewhere that lays out all the items that are sent to the ISS on each resupply spacecraft. I understand that getting full lists of every item sent might be a stretch, but maybe a list of the general/common items that are sent is available somewhere.

**Does anyone know of such a list, or where I might be able to search for one?** Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
A good example of the stuff I'm looking for can be found in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iI2FyLVXGo). The man in the video explains how so many different things are sent to the space station and then provides some examples. I want a more full list if it's possible!

Answer (score 24):

If you want an example manifest for one logistics flight, that's available.

Search terms...suggest "ISS Cargo Manifest"

From [SpaceX 2 Cargo Manifest](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/729030main_spacex_2_cargo_manifest.pdf)

(see link for details)

- 81 kg of crew supplies (food, clothes, paperwork)
- 25 kg of international partner experiments
- 323 kg of NASA experiments
- 3 kg of EVA tools
- 135 kg of ISS hardware
- 8 kg of PC parts
- 0.3 kg of Russian hardware

Comment: Pretty solid answer. Thanks! I wonder if there is a more specific list. What do you think?

Comment: I'm surprised the ratio of food to science is that low. Is this typical?

Comment: @ikrase food is transported dehydrated remember, so weighs much less than you would first expect.

Comment: No consumables like oxygen or water?

Comment: @MartinSchröder while there are some shipments of water and backup oxygen, they aren't treated as consumables where you need constant supply from earth - most water is recycled and most oxygen is created on-site from water electrolysis.

Comment: That also hinges on the fact that 300kg is a lot of science (which is all going to be minimal-mass, because space.)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Water is usually brought extra, for example HTV-4 brought 480 litre.

Comment: @MartinSchröder. Oxygen and water are technically not consumables, at least not water. See Frank Herbert's "Dune" for reference.

Answer (score 12):

Based on @Martin Schroeder comment. I found out a cargo with water supply:

https://spaceflight101.com/progress-ms-03/cargo-manifest/

420kg of water out of a 2405kg payload.

Presumably, There are lighter and heavier shipments.

Comment: Yeah this answers it a bit more. I was definitely hoping to find more details. Maybe something on the variation of the food as well. I also wonder how they store the water. Is it just in large containers, or is it one large tank that is then pumped into the ISS?